# AttributeError: 'openvino.inference_engine.ie_api.InferRequest' object has no attribute 'outputs'

Tags: python, pytorch, openvino

I am trying to use Openvino async inference model in python. (https://docs.openvino.ai/2020.1/ie_python_api/classie__api_1_1ExecutableNetwork.html)

```py
infer_request_handle = exec_net.start_async(
        request_id=0, inputs={input_blob: img})
infer_status = infer_request_handle.wait()
res = exec_net.outputs['output']
```

but I met "AttributeError: 'openvino.inference_engine.ie_api.InferRequest' object has no attribute 'outputs'" errors.
I wanna get output feature. How can I get?

Answer (score 0):

The *infer_request_handle.outputs[out_blob_name]* has been deprecated in later OpenVINO version.

Use [output_blobs](https://docs.openvino.ai/2022.1/api/ie_python_api/_autosummary/openvino.inference_engine.InferRequest.html) to get the dictionary that maps the output layer names to corresponding Blobs and then use [buffer](https://docs.openvino.ai/2022.1/api/ie_python_api/_autosummary/openvino.inference_engine.Blob.html) to print out the Blob’s memory as numpy.ndarray representation.

```
res = infer_request_handle.output_blobs[out_blob_name]
print(res.buffer)
```